# Using socket.id to identify user for chat application

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I am new to node.js and facing problem using socket.id to identify logged in user. on client side user login using email id and password which is verified from a table on server side and if verified, user socket.id is used to send a username to that client.

When two user login; they can chat with unique username but when chat page is refreshed both username get changed to username of second login(i.e. user who logged in later). Please help.

Here is my code
server.js

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, Twit = require('twit')
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, os = require('os')
, open = require('open')
, bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, connect = require('connect')
, mysql = require("mysql");

var clients = {};

server.listen(9383,'192.168.1.3');

var name1;

app.get('/loginstyle.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/loginstyle.css');
});

app.get('/loginme', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/loginmysql.html');
});

app.get('/option', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/option.html');
});

app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

app.post('/valid', function (req, res) {

  var username=req.body.email;
  var password=req.body.pass;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "vk123",
    "database": "login"
  });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM id WHERE email=? AND password=?', [username,password], function(err, rows){

    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      for (var i in rows) {

          name1=rows[i].name;

          io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            clients[socket.id] = socket;
            clients[socket.id].emit('name', name1); // username is sent to client
           });

          res.redirect('http://192.168.1.3:9383/chat');
      }
    }
  });

connection.end();
});


  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(name,msg){

      console.log(msg);    
      io.emit('chatmessage',name,msg);
    });
  });
```

client.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body background="/bgimage.jpg">
        <div class="chat"></div>    

        <form style="bottom:10px; position:fixed; padding-left: 100px">
            <input type="text" class="msg" style="width:1000px; height:30px"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="enter" style="padding-left:0px; height:35px; background-color:skyblue">Send</button>
        </form>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:9383');
            var username;
            var chatmsg=[];

            socket.on('name', function(name){
                username=name;
                console.log(username);
            });


        $('.enter').bind("click",function(){
                chatmsg.push({chatname:username, msgtext:($('.msg').val())});
                socket.emit('chat message',username,$('.msg').val() );
                $('.msg').val('');
                return false;
            });

            socket.on('chatmessage', function(name,msg){

                var block= $("<div class='message'> </div>");
                if(msg.length){
                    var messenger= $("<div style='color:green;font-weight:bold;background-color:floralwhite'> </div>");
                    messenger.append(name);
                    block.append(messenger);
                    var text=$("<div style='padding:3px;background-color:floralwhite'></div>");
                    text.append(msg);
                    block.append(text);
                    block.append($("<div style='padding:10px;background-color:transparent'></div>"));
                    $('.chat').append(block);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you are running into the [closure inside loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) problem in your for loop. Also, you shouldn't [use for...in to iterate over arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I removed the loop then also not working.                                  name1=rows[0].name;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   clients[socket.id] = socket;
   clients[socket.id].emit('name', name1);
});